# How to send attachments from a MUC room using ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

This is the MUC configuration i have in my ejabberd.yml file

`mod_muc:
    access: muc
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_admin: muc_admin`

Do ejabberd support attachments in rooms? If so what is the configuration to be added in the configuration?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP does not support attachment per see. You can negotiate file transfer out of band but this is not "attachments".

You should look into the following extensions:

- [XEP_0234: Jingle File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html)
- [XEP-0096: SI File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html)
- [XEP-0363: HTTP File Upload](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html)

This is usually to implement on the client side (interpret those messages and do the right thing for transfer).